# How to get prereleased packages list using Nuget.Core?

Tags: nuget, nugetgallery

I'm trying to use `Nuget.Core` to find `Microsoft.Bcl.Immutable` package (it is currently in prerelease state). `DataServicePackageRepository.SupportsPrereleasePackages` always returns `false` and I can't find any way to change it.

Id there a way to work with prereleased packages, located at nuget.org using Nuget.Core APIs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was using v1 nuget API, located at `http://packages.nuget.org/v1/FeedService.svc/`.
Second version API `http://packages.nuget.org/api/v2/` supports exposing prereleased packages in search results.

Comment: Change this in Tools -> Library Package Manager -> Package Manager Settings -> Package Manager -> Package Sources